# Calculating column differences while handling NA's

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and have encountered an interesting problem. My dataset has a lot of NA's and handling them has become a bit problematic.

What I have:

```
  S1 S2 S3 S4
  NA NA 3  4
  1  3  NA NA
  3  NA 5  NA
```

What I want to do: Calculate Diff = S4 - S3 - S2 - S1. But if S4 is NA then it should do Diff = S3 - S2 - S1. And so on... But if lets say, S4 and S2 are NA's then the Diff should be S3 - S1.

For example in row 2 the answer should be 2. (3-1)

What I need:

```
 S1 S2 S3 S4 Diff
 NA NA 3  4  1
 1  3  NA NA 2
 3  NA 5  NA 2
```

What I have written up till now: (but doesn't work for handling NA's)

```
data <- cbind(data, Diff = data$S4 - data$S3 -data$S2 -data$S1)
```

Additional Info: The values under each column in the original problem are timestamps.

What the data looks like:

```
head(select(data,S4,S3,S2,S1))

  S4                  S3                  S2                  S1                    
1 2020-07-08 07:46:36 NA                  2020-07-08 07:08:31 NA                 
2 2020-07-08 07:11:57 NA                  2020-07-08 07:08:53 NA                 
3 2020-07-08 07:12:50 NA                  2020-07-08 07:09:40 NA                 
4 2020-07-08 07:13:14 NA                  2020-07-08 07:09:42 NA                 
5 2020-07-08 07:13:46 NA                  2020-07-08 07:10:36 NA                 
6 2020-07-08 07:44:45 NA                  2020-07-08 07:11:42 NA
```

Updated Version of dataset:
(Contains the most accurate representation of the dataset - timestamps are converted to seconds.) What I need? The "Diff" column.

```
  S4  S3  S2  S1 Diff                    
1 NA  30  40  NA 10                
1 NA  30  NA  40 10                
1 10  30  40  50 40                
1 30  NA  40  NA 10                
1 10  30  40  NA 30                
1 NA  30  40  50 20
```

Found the answer here: [Take difference between first and last observations in a row, where each row is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57437497/take-difference-between-first-and-last-observations-in-a-row-where-each-row-is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R option via `apply`

```
df$Diff <- apply(df,1,function(x) 2*tail(na.omit(x),1)-sum(x,na.rm = TRUE))
```

or

```
df$Diff <- apply(df,1,function(x) Reduce("-",rev(na.omit(x))))
```

such that

```
> df
  S1 S2 S3 S4 Diff
1 NA NA  3  4    1
2  1  3 NA NA    2
3  3 NA  5 NA    2
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(S1 = c(NA, 1L, 3L), S2 = c(NA, 3L, NA), S3 = c(3L, 
NA, 5L), S4 = c(4L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

---

## Edit

When with timestamp values, maybe you can try the code below

```
df$Diff <- apply(df,1,function(x) Reduce("-",as.POSIXlt(rev(na.omit(x)))))
```

such that

```
> df
  S1                  S2 S3                  S4      Diff
1 NA 2020-07-08 07:08:31 NA 2020-07-08 07:46:36 38.083333
2 NA 2020-07-08 07:08:53 NA 2020-07-08 07:11:57  3.066667
3 NA 2020-07-08 07:09:40 NA 2020-07-08 07:12:50  3.166667
4 NA 2020-07-08 07:09:42 NA 2020-07-08 07:13:14  3.533333
5 NA 2020-07-08 07:10:36 NA 2020-07-08 07:13:46  3.166667
6 NA 2020-07-08 07:11:42 NA 2020-07-08 07:44:45 33.050000
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(S1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), S2 = c("2020-07-08 07:08:31",
"2020-07-08 07:08:53", "2020-07-08 07:09:40", "2020-07-08 07:09:42",
"2020-07-08 07:10:36", "2020-07-08 07:11:42"), S3 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), S4 = c("2020-07-08 07:46:36", "2020-07-08 07:11:57",
"2020-07-08 07:12:50", "2020-07-08 07:13:14", "2020-07-08 07:13:46",
"2020-07-08 07:44:45")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
"6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. While this is an elegant solution, could you tell me how would you edit it to allow for timestamp information. The question above was a simplistic version of the original problem. The values of columns are timestamps and it doesn't allow for 2*tail() operation.

Comment: @SyedAhmed I added another approach, please check it out

Comment: It throws the error:  Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : non-numeric argument to binary operator. Not sure if it is handling the NA properly. I'll share the head(data) in the question.

Comment: @SyedAhmed Could you use a small example with timestamp values? Otherwise it is difficult to follow what kind of errors occurs.

Comment: Edited the question with the timestamp values.

Comment: Hi Thomas, apologies for the delay, the edit that you mentioned only works when every consecutive column is filled with NA. So for example, if you change the dataframe structure and add one time stamp value in any row in column S3, then the code would fail.

Comment: @SyedAhmed No worries. If you have three values, for example, `S4`, `S3` and `S1`, you will have the interval between `S4-S3`, but you cannot use an interval to subtract another timestamp, since the former is the relative, while the latter is absolute

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this problem? Should I convert timestamps to seconds and then do it?

Comment: @SyedAhmed No, I don't think that is a programming problem. From physical perspective, it is meaningless to use a relative time interval to subtract a time point

Comment: I understand now. Could you check the updated version of the dataset in the question. The "Diff" column is the difference between the first filled row and the last filled row. That is what is required. Eitherway, thank you so much for sticking around and replying. :)

Comment: @SyedAhmed It seems you have already found the answer :)